# Toggle icon not showing unless I click it

Tags: javascript, html, darkmode

I am using a dark mode code. With this code, I want to toggle between dark mode and light mode using respective icons. This works perfectly, but the only issue is dark/light icon is not shown by default when page loads. If I click the icon, then only it shows. How can I make it show by default when page loads.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
  const switcher = document.querySelector("#switcher");
    switcher.setAttribute('src', '...LIGHT-MODE-1.png');

    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (currentTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
        }
    }

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
            switcher.setAttribute('src', '...LIGHT-MODE-1.png');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
            switcher.setAttribute('src', '...DARK-MODE-1.png');
        }
    }
    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```html
<!--The icon HTML-->


<label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
        <span title="Enable/disable Dark Mode"><img id="switcher" src=""></span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /></label>
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're missing the `src` change in the first dark mode check:

```js
if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    switcher.setAttribute('src', '...DARK-MODE-1.png');
}
```

**Update:** Instead of all the duplicate code, I would recommend creating one function that sets the theme, which you can then call from anywhere. This will allow you to use it at initial load, and on click:

```js
const switcher = document.querySelector('#switcher');
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function setTheme(theme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);

    const src = '/path/to/images/' + (theme === 'light' ? 'LIGHT-MODE-1.png' : 'DARK-MODE-1.png');
    switcher.setAttribute('src', src);
}

const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
setTheme(theme);

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const theme = e.currentTarget.checked ? 'dark' : 'light';
    setTheme(theme);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjzue6wa/1/

Comment: I am using the source as complete link to icon with my domain name on my site and actual page. To avoid posting a link here, I removed it. Issue still persists.

Comment: I've rewritten the provided code to show an alternative way of doing it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I fixed the icon issue as per my previous comment. But the code is now not toggling between light and dark mode. Pls help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the currentTarget in e.currentTarget.checked; does this work now? Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjzue6wa/1/

Comment: Yes, its working now! Thanks for all your help, really appreciate that :)